# Get the result of ajax call to array and them print it

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've been searching long time to solve this issue with no luck.
This is my ajax call:

```
function vehicles () {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://some.url',
        data: '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error vehicles');
        }
    });
}

function fillVehicles() {
    vehicles().done(function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index) {
            $('#write-here').append('<div>'+data[index]+'</div>');
        });
    });
}

fillVehicles();
```

And it works fine. The result is the "div" items print properly.
But this is not what I need.

What I would like to do is:

```
function vehicles () {
    //...the same as before...
}

var arrVehicles = new Array();

function fillVehicles() {
    vehicles().done(function(data){
        arrVehicles = data;
    });
}

fillVehicles();

$.each(arrVehicles, function(index) {
    $('#write-here').append('<div>'+arrVehicles[index]+'</div>');
});
```

But the result is that the "div" items are not shown in any way. And this is happening because the printing gets executed before the ajax call is done, so arrVehicles is empty.

In short, what I need is to get the data from the ajax call, put them into an array and then play with the array as I please.

I know making the call ajax async=false would work... but I need the benefits of async=true.
Seriously... I've been searching a lot and trying many solutions with no luck.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't do it the way you want due to async nature of ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've mentioned in my comment you can't write code the way you want due to async nature of client server communication. Well, atleast not in javascript. 
Deal with it. And welcome to the world of promises. :)

If you want to make async data to be accessible any time after loading you can store it in a form of Promise.

```
//vehicles will be a 'promise' to return data
var vehicles = $.post('some_url', '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'); 

//do whatever you need to by passing a function
vehicles.done(function(vehicles) {
   console.log(vehicles); //is array here
});

//for example render
vehicles.done(function(vehicles) {
   $('#write-here').html('<div>' + vehicles.join('</div><div>') + '</div>');
});
```

You can even create another promises by using `.then`

```
var hasAudi = vehicles.then(function(vehicles){
   return vehicles.indexOf('Audi') >= 0;
});

hasAudi.done(function(hasAudi) {
   console.log(hasAudi ? 'There is audi.' : 'No OOOO found');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Yury. I'll check what you say about promises and let you know. Thanks again.